# French spell check for texMaker is not working?

Tags: texmaker, french, spelling, grammar

i'm trying to correct my report using texmaker i have downloaded and added the french language to texmaker

[image: texMaker configuration for french spell chcker]
But when i click on the spell check button a window appears but no suggestions or corrections are made or proposed

I'm using texmaker 4.5 on windows 7_64
can someone help , thanks

Comment: I have suggestions right-clicking on the underlined words.

Comment: @Bernard thanks i didn't noticed the changes in the text editor because i have focused on the window that appeared .. you can put it as an answer

Comment: @Franskenstein: Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just right-click on the underlined words.